# Python plot horizontal line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

By using the stated code, the plot that created is as follows:
[image]

```
plt.figure()
plt.axhline(y=6, xmin=0.1-0.05, xmax=0.1+0.05, color='r', linewidth=2, label='Apple')
plt.axhline(y=5, xmin=0.22-0.05, xmax=0.22+0.05, color='b', linewidth=2, label='Grape')

plt.axhline(y=3, xmin=0.4-0.05, xmax=0.4+0.05, color='r', linewidth=2, label='Apple')
plt.axhline(y=2, xmin=0.52-0.05, xmax=0.52+0.05, color='b', linewidth=2, label='Grape')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I would like to plot like this:

[image]

What is the proper plot to achieve the ideal plot?

Comment: Maybe use "grouped bar chart"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`seaborn.pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Grape', 'Grape'],
                   'category': ['Category1', 'Category2',
                                'Category1', 'Category2'],
                   'value': [6, 3, 5, 2],
                  })

ax = sns.pointplot(df, x='category', y='value', hue='fruit',
                   dodge=0.2, marker='_', markersize=20,
                   ls='none')

# ax.set_ylim(bottom=0) # optional start the Y-axis from 0
```

Output:

[image]

Variant from a wide input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category1': {'Apple': 6, 'Grape': 5},
                   'Category2': {'Apple': 3, 'Grape': 2},
                  })

df = df.rename_axis('fruit').reset_index().melt('fruit', var_name='category')
# or
# df = df.rename_axis(index='fruit', columns='category').stack().reset_index(name='value')
```